# Getting issue in { get; set; } syntax in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting productTestInformation as `null` at set.

```
 public class ProductLog
    {
        public ProductTestInformation productTestInformation { get; set; }

        public int? ProductId { get { return productTestInformation .ProductId; } set { productTestInformation .ProductId = value; } }
        public string ProductName { get { return productTestInformation .ProductName; } set { productTestInformation .ProductName = value; } }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize your object. Like this in C# 6 :

```
public ProductTestInformation productTestInformation { get; set; } 
                                                           = new ProductTestInformation();
```

The default value for a Reference Type is `NULL`. Since you didn't initialize your object (using the `new` keyword). Then it is referring to `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

productTestInformation will always be null until you set from it.

If you would like it to return a new object try something like this:

```
private ProductTestInformation _productTestInformation;
public ProductTestInformation productTestInformation { 
    get { return _productTestInformation ?? (_productTestInformation = new ProductTestInformation()); }
    set {_productTestInformation = value;} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initilize "productTestInformation" in Constructor

```
public class ProductLog
{
    public ProductTestInformation productTestInformation { get; set; }

    public int? ProductId { get { return productTestInformation .ProductId; } set { productTestInformation .ProductId = value; } }
    public string ProductName { get { return productTestInformation .ProductName; } set { productTestInformation .ProductName = value; } }

    public ProductLog()
    {
        this.productTestInformation = new ProductTestInformation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

public class ProductLog

```
{
    private ProductTestInformation _productTestInformation;

    public ProductLog(ProductTestInformation productTestInformation)
    {
        _productTestInformation = productTestInformation;
    }

    public int? ProductId { get { return _productTestInformation.ProductId; } set { _productTestInformation.ProductId = value; } }
    public string ProductName { get { return _productTestInformation.ProductName; } set { _productTestInformation.ProductName = value; } }

}

public class ProductTestInformation 
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult View() 
    {
        var productTestInfo = new ProductTestInformation();// or get from the db
        var productlog = new ProductLog(productTestInfo);

        return View();
    }
}
```